# jQuery slideToggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have this jquery code which displays my div and hides it no problem but im having trouble changing it from css display to slideToggle display?

```
$('li.trigger').hover(
        function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#fff'); $('div', this).css('display', 'block'); },
        function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#fff'); $('div', this).css('display', 'none'); });
```

Comment: u want to slide toggle everytime they put the mouseenter or mouseenter/leave because ur toggling while mouse enter first mouseenter slides it hidden, then second time,slides it visible, and so on

Comment: sorry see above the edit.  This works changing just the css display block and display none but i want it to slide toggle open on mouseover and slide close on mouseout

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go, if u dnt need to slide the `div`s then just move `.slideUp()` to the line above same with `slideDown`

```
$('li.trigger').hover(
        function() { 
            $(this).css('background-color', '#fff'); 
            $('div', this).css('display', 'block').slideUp(); 
        },
        function() { 
            $(this).css('background-color', '#fff'); 
            $('div', this).css('display', 'none').slideDown(); 
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.trigger').hover(
        function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#0099ff');
 $('div', this).css('display', 'block').slideToggle("slow"); 

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Heres what worked

```
$('li.trigger').hover(
    function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');$('div', this).slideToggle("slow"); 
});
```

Comment: Your answer here is basically identical to the previous posts; please don't repeat other answers unless there is something substantially different about your approach.